# Bypassing a blocked port 21 to access my FTP server

Tags: firewall, ftp, port

I want to edit a not very big file on my website. For this I need FTP. But the WiFi at the place I'm currently staying at doesn't allow any connection via port 21.

I've read that you can use an intermediate server via SSH, but I do not have access to such a server.

How can I connect to my FTP server?

Comment: If your ISP blocks port 21, then configure the FTP server, to run on a different port.

Comment: @Ramhound I sadly don't have access to the FTP server's configuration, so I can't change the port.

Comment: Are you sure FTP is blocked, and not just some types of FTP? Have you tried toggling between active and passive FTP?

Answer (score 1):

Contact a VPN provider and set up a VPN. This will allow you to tunnel FTP (and all other) traffic across the VPN bypassing the restrictions on your connection.

Alternatively, tether your computer to your cellphone and use Cellular data to do the FTP edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a web-based FTP service. Below are some free such websites :

- [Ali's FTP Interface](http://myftp.alishomepage.com/)
- [TXFTP](http://www.txftp.com/)
- [SmoothFTP](http://www.smoothftp.com/cgi-bin/smoothftp/index.cgi)

Some of these are quite old, but might still be working.

Comment: Be aware that this will give your credentials to an unknown third party who can use them to hack into your site.